# Can a GCP Reseller/MSP see in his billing reports which projects are assigned to which of his customers?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

As a managed service provider or a reseller, can I see in my GCP billing report/Invoice which project is linked to each of my customers (in one report or with a one API call and not per separately customer)?
So I won’t need to manually match between projects and it’s relevant customer when I prepare their invoice).

Comment: I would suggest to reach out to Cloud Billing in regards to this inquiry. You can contact the billing team using the methods mentioned here https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/support#contact-billing-support

Comment: Hello. Unfortunately GCP billing support is not that useful if you don't have an account that supports the use case you are asking for. 
As I'm developing the capability I'm asking about, I'll be happy to hear some answers from MSPs, Resellers or Pros that are familiar with what GCP enables them.